# Swagger Problem after Adding Authorization in .NET

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

First of all, I want to explain that this is a Web API that I'm doing to learn. It's my first web API and I'm new. Well, the API was working fine with Swagger since the moment I added authorization with the bearer token.

Error Swagger Throws: [image: Error]

The class Swagger is referring to in the error:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IncidentManagerAPI.Security
{
    [Route("oauth")]
    public class OAuthController : Controller
    {
        [Route("token"), BasicAuthorization]
        public IActionResult Token()
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var authenticatedUser = new AuthenticatedUser(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, true, "incidentmanagerapp");
            var accessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(tokenHandler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity(authenticatedUser),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
                Issuer = "incidentmanagerapi",
                Audience = "incidentmanagerapp",
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("IncidentMaster2021.exe!")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
                IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
            }));
            return Ok(new { accessToken, token_type = "bearer", expires_in = 60 });
        }
    }
}
```

As I said I'm pretty new and If somebody can explain why am I doing wrong I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is in the error message.

Comment: @IanKemp Please respect, I said I'm new and I didn't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put http verb attribute on controller method ex. `[HttpGet()]`